# How to Copy Attributes to Inner Element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm writing a very simple directive for AngularJS that is supposed to transform something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="FirstName" mydirectivename />
```

Into something like this:

```
<span><input type="text" name="FirstName" /></span>
```

It was easy enough to get here:

```
<span type="text" name="FirstName"><input/><span>
```

But now I'm down in the weeds writing a compile function doing things that the documentation says "you should rarely need to do" and I'm thinking I'm off track. Is there a simple way to indicate that a specific element in a template should be the target of copied attributes?

Thanks

Comment: check out this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42319665/913845

Answer (score 0):

For your simple example here you can use something like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/BbwBLa?p=preview

The plunker will transclude the original element and reinsert it inside the wrapping element.

Alternatively you follow the other answer and specify everything you want to copy, for more control.

If you need to copy *all* attributes and you have a recent enough angular version (1.1.4 onwards, looking through the docs http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/guide/directive) then you can try template functions which are described in the the link. These are given all of the original element's attributes and can use them to write a new template with the original attributes. I wouldn't recommend using template functions this way though as its a little too fiddly for my liking.

**Edit**

This does what you want in your simple example, very simply, in the link function. This should really go in the compile I think, but plunker went crazy when I put it in there. http://plnkr.co/edit/PLfSU6?p=preview

Comment: Actually reading your comments below, I think this will also keep the original attributes on the outer element. So just more options to do the same thing...

Comment: Yeah, I've actually gotten this working a couple of different ways, but I don't think I'm doing it in an orthodox way and I'm just trying to learn at this point. For example I can do this easily in the link delegate, but this is an extremely simple example. I think if you had a more complex template you wouldn't want to write a bunch of code to create the necessary elements. I can do it using the compile attribute too, but the amount of code I had to write seems pretty ridiculous for something so simple--this is just one short line of jQuery code compared to several dozen.

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
.directive("myDirective", function ($state) {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            replace: true,
            controller: function(){},
            template: function (element, attrs) {}
```

Answer (score -2):

what about :

```
.directive("mydirectivename", function ($state) {
        return {
            restrict: "A",
            replace: true,
            template: '<span ng-transclude></span>',
```

Comment: if you could explain more about what this code does, it would be more helpful